# Cron Jobs login on website

Tags: php, server, cron, jobs

I am currently hosting a website on a developer's server. The server requires me to logon every so often or they will delete my account and my entire website. They do support cron jobs. I am wondering how to set up a cron job that would login to the server every so often. The cron job maker is set up like this:

minute:

hour:

day:

month:

weekday:

command:

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: A: get a better host and/or pay for one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding something like this to the cron:

```
 curl -d "username=<USERNAME>&password=<PASSWORD>" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST http://<WEBSITE>/session/signin
```